# Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<Device, number, { dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>; }>' but required in type 'AnyAction'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to dispatch an action (don't know if it's the right name, because I'm really new to redux and redux-toolkit) and I'm getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<Device, number, { dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<Device, number, { dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>; }>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.  TS2345

    18 |     if (hasGetError) push('/');
    19 |     else {
  > 20 |       dispatch(getDeviceById(deviceId));
       |                ^
    21 |     }
    22 |   }, [push, hasGetError, dispatch, deviceId]);
    23 |
```

Here is my code:

store\index.ts

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import createRootReducer from './reducers';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: createRootReducer(history),
  middleware: [routerMiddleware(history), thunkMiddleware],
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

features\device\redux\deviceOperations.ts

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { AppDispatch } from 'src/store';
import { loaderActions } from '../../../features/loader/redux';
import deviceManager from '../deviceManager';

export const getDeviceById = createAsyncThunk<
  Device,
  number,
  {
    dispatch: AppDispatch;
  }
>('device/GET_DEVICE_BY_ID', async (deviceId: number, thunkApi) => {
  thunkApi.dispatch(loaderActions.start('getDeviceById'));
  try {
    const device = await deviceManager.getDeviceById(deviceId);
    return { ...device, deviceId };
  } finally {
    thunkApi.dispatch(loaderActions.stop('getDeviceById'));
  }
});

interface Device {
  deviceId: number;
  name: string;
}
```

The part that is causing this error seems to be a custom hook (I'm following another project, but I don't really understand why I need this custom hook and how to use it in my component, I'm really following the example).

features\device\hooks\useGetDeviceById.ts

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from 'src/hooks';
import { fetchStatus } from 'src/shared/constants';
import { getDeviceById } from 'src/features/device/redux/deviceOperations';
import {
  getDevice,
  getDeviceFetchError,
} from 'src/features/device/redux/deviceSelectors';

const useGetDeviceById = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { push } = useHistory();
  const { deviceId } = useParams<{ deviceId?: string }>();

  const device = useAppSelector(getDevice);
  const hasGetError = useAppSelector(getDeviceFetchError);
  const isDeviceLoading =
    device.fetchStatus.getProposalById !== fetchStatus.fulfilled;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasGetError) push('/');
    else {
      dispatch(getDeviceById(deviceId)); // ERROR
    }
  }, [push, hasGetError, dispatch, deviceId]);

  return { device: { ...device, deviceId }, isDeviceLoading };
};

export default useGetDeviceById;
```

How can I fix it? And if I'm not asking much, why would I really need this custom hook?

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are running into is because you are overriding the middleware that redux-toolkit usually applies which sets up the type definitions properly.

You can fix the issue using [getDefaultMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware) which will allow you to concat on the connected router middleware without ruining the setup.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { routerMiddleware } from "connected-react-router/immutable";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import createRootReducer from "./reducers";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: createRootReducer(history),
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(routerMiddleware(history))
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Here's an approximation of the code (enough at least for those type errors to show/be fixed):

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-taussig-oweoj?file=/src/useGetDeviceById.ts